# O que significa "{{ __('Login') }}" no arquivo de layouts do Laravel?

Tags: laravel

No arquivo `\resources\layouts\app.blade.php` tem o seguinte trecho na linha **37**:

```
{{ __('Login') }}
```

Ao que parece isso é um Helper. Mas qual seu significado/funcionamento? Pergunto isso pois dependendo do caso quero ver se é possível realizar implementações derivadas dela.

Laravel 5.6

Comment: isso ta na instalação nova?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A função "helper" `__()` do laravel realiza a tradução da string ou chave de tradução conforme a localização do usuário, como informado [na documentação oficial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-__). Você pode passar ambos configurando segundo seus arquivos de [localização](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/localization):

**Exemplo:**

*resources/lang/pt/messages.php:*

```
return [
    'welcome' => 'Seja bem-vindo a site!'
];
```

*resources/lang/es/messages.php:*

```
return [
    'welcome' => 'Bienvenido al sitio!'
];
```

Para exibir o trecho com tradução:

```
echo __('messages.welcome'); //se espanhol: 'Bienvenido al sitio!', se português: 'Seja bem-vindo ao site!'
```

Você também pode utilizar strings literais para realizar a tradução, usando arquivos `.json` dentro do mesmo diretório:

*resources/lang/es.json:*

```
{
    "Eu amo programar.": "Me encanta programar."
}
```

Para exibir:

```
echo __('Eu amo programar'); //se espanhol: 'Me encanta programar.'
```

Comment: Legal, e esse ```{{ __('Login') }}``` ele busca em que arquivo por default?

Comment: Não há um arquivo default. Se você setar `__('login.usuario')`, por exemplo, e você não possuir um arquivo com os parâmetros da linguagem que você configurou, a string aparecerá literalmente `"login.usuario"` na página. O que você pode fazer é utilizar uma String como `Nome de usuário` e depois configurar as linguagens para traduzir essa String utilizando jsons. De qualquer maneira você deverá utilizar o [localization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/localization) para fazer traduções.